# Shell write to file if variable is lower than float

Tags: shell

I have the following shell code.

```
i=0
while read name pren med
do
   i=`expr $i + 1`
   while read name2 pren2 n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6 n7
   do
      if [ $name$pren = $name2$pren2 ]
         then
            MED[$i]=`expr $n1 + $n2 + $n3 + $n4 + $n5 + $n6 + $n7`
            MED[$i]=`echo "scale=2;${MED[$i]}/7" | bc -l `
            MED[$i]=`echo "scale=2;($med+${MED[$i]})/2" | bc -l ` 
            PERS[$i]="$name $pren ${MED[$i]}"
            *echo ${PERS[$i]} >> notefinale
      fi    
  done <$2
done <$1
```

The code reads from 2 files a Name , Second Name and some grades. After that it evaluates the average grade which is MED[$i], anyway i want to make the echo marked with a "*" , only if the MED[$i] is higher than > 8.5 . How can i write this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using bc, multiply the value by 10, store it in a temp variable and then compare it to 85.

If you're having an issue that the value is still a non-integer following the use of bc, then you can use:

```
tmpvar=`printf "%0.0f" $float_value`
```

bash does not have built in support for floating point arithmetic for the comparison operations, so, for example, doing the multiplication:

```
med_int=`echo "scale=0; ${MED[$i]} * 10" | bc -l`
# force into an integer
med_int=`printf "%0.0f" $med_int`
if [ $med_int -gt 85 ]; then
    echo ${PERS[$i]} >> notefile
fi
```